# How to repair corrupted NetBeans cache on 8.2 and 11.0?

Tags: netbeans

I'm using JDK 1.0.8_131 and NetBeans IDE 8.2 on Kubuntu 18.04 but it seems cache is being corrupted.

When there's no syntax error in a project, error appear on project node. 
But when I cancel run, output is as follow:

```
/home/kubuntu/.cache/netbeans/11.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:24:
```

I tried close project and deleting cache from  :

`/home/kubuntu/.cache/netbeans/11.0/executor-snippets/run.xml`
`/home/kubuntu/cache/netbeans/11.0/index/`
`/home/kubuntu/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml`
`/home/kubuntu/cache/netbeans/8.2/index/`

but it wouldn't be solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the Help->About menu entry it will show you information about the version of NetBeans, including the cache directory. You can then copy that path to the clipboard and close NetBeans. Make sure that the NetBeans application is really stopped, sometimes the UI might be gone but the process could still be running in the background. If needed wait a bit and kill the remaining process (if you are having issues with NetBeans then it could stay behind like that). Now that the process is not running anymore you can delete all files from the directory you copied to the clipboard with something like 'rm -rf $directory', where $directory is where you paste the clipboard entry.